# suma de elementos de una array con recursividad

Tags: javascript, array, algoritmos, recursión

estoy intentando resolver este problema pero siempre entro en un error de recursividad, alguien motivado a intentarlo?

We define super digit of an integer
using the following rules:

- Given an integer, we need to find the super digit of the integer **x**.
- If **x** has only one digit, then its super digit is **x**.

Otherwise, the super digit of **x** is equal to the super digit of the sum of the digits of **x**.

For example, the super digit of 9875
will be calculated as:

```
super_digit(9875)       9+8+7+5 = 29 

super_digit(29)     2 + 9 = 11
super_digit(11)     1 + 1 = 2
super_digit(2)      = 2
```

Knowing this, our function will recieve an string as first parameter and an integer as the second one.

**Example:**
n = '9875';
k = 4;
The number p is created by concatenating the string **n**, **k** times so the initial.
p = '9875987598759875'

```
superDigit(p) = superDigit(9875987598759875)
              9+8+7+5+9+8+7+5+9+8+7+5+9+8+7+5 = 116
superDigit(p) = superDigit(116)
              1+1+6 = 8
superDigit(p) = superDigit(8)
```

All of the digits of p sum 116. The digits of 116 sum 8.

8 is only one digit, so it is the super digit.

**Esta es mi solución**

```
 const superDigit = (n, k) => {
 let num='';
 let res=0;
 if(k){
  for(let i=0;i<k;i++){
      num+=n
  }
 num=num.split('')
 }else{
 num=n.split('')
 }
 res=num.reduce((a,b)=>parseInt(a)+parseInt(b)) 
 return res.toString().lenght === 1 ? res.toString() : superDigit(res.toString());
```

}

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.SO], por favor evita poner textos en inglés o tu pregunta podría ser cerrada.

Comment: La palabra no es animarse a intentarlo. Es animarse a resolverlo. Aun así, tal y como dice Pipe, tu pregunta está mayormente en inglés (debido al enunciado del ejercicio) y eso podría ser motivo de cierre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como te dije en mi comentario anterior, el proceso de repetir el string lo debes hacer solo al inicio, aqui te dejo una solución mas compacta y mas organizada

```js
const sumarDigitos = (num) => num.toString().split('').reduce((a,d) => Number(a)+Number(d), 0);
 
const calcularSuperDigito = num => {
  let sum = sumarDigitos(num);
  if(sum.toString().split('').length === 1)
     return sum;
  else
     return calcularSuperDigito(sum);
}
 const superDigito = (n, k) => {
   n = n.toString();
   if(k){ //Si se especifica k, repetimos el string
    n = n.repeat(k);
   }
   
   return calcularSuperDigito(n); //Calculamos el super digito con ese string repetido (pero no lo repetimos nunca mas)
}

console.log(superDigito(9875,4));
```